# Google Photos API add to album

Tags: php, google-photos, google-photos-api

I am getting a error I cannot work out the reason for in

```
   public function album_addIds($itemIds, $albumId) {
        if (!is_array($itemIds)) {
          $itemIds = [$itemIds];
        }
        try {
          $response = $this->service->batchAddMediaItemsToAlbum($albumId, $itemIds);
        } catch (\Exception $ex) {
          $noop = 1;
        }
      }
```

Which give the highly helpful error message:

```
" Expect array. "
```

when the Exception occurs.
$albumId is a string and as per code (and checking at breakpoint) $itemIds is an array.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the *PHP* sample code?  The arguments in the sample code are the wrong way round

Google wrote:

```
$response = $photosLibraryClient->batchAddMediaItemsToAlbum($albumId, $mediaItemIds);
```

whereas the correct code is

```
    $response = $photosLibraryClient->batchAddMediaItemsToAlbum($mediaItemIds, $albumId);
```

The OAuth sample code is also wrong, infuriatingly.  They assign the access_token to the creds session variable, where they mean refresh_token

Comment: Yes, I forgot to update question - so as you answered already its accepted answer. Had to trawl through the API code to discover this. Its a really bad API and very very limited